# Suppress counting of fbox, parbox, minipage as table

Tags: tables, numbering, minipage, parbox, fbox

I am running into an issue where either the fbox, parbox, or minipage is being counted as a table. As an example, I have added sample code that is similar to my setup. This code results in the first table being numbered as Table 1 and the second table (after the fbox) being numbered as Table 3. Clearly the fbox is not a table but is for some reason being counted as a table.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[font=small,skip=5pt,belowskip=-1pt]{caption}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.4cm}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-1pt}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\fancyhead{}
\makeatletter
\let\@authorsaddresses\@empty
\makeatother

\acmConference[SIGIR '20]{XXX}{XXX}{XXX}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} 
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{appendix}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}% for centering text horizontally

\usepackage{array}\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column

\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}

\newcommand\boldgray[1]{\cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\boldGrey[1]{\cellcolor{LightGrey}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~~~~\textbullet~~}

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\vspace{-.1cm}
\small
\caption{Caption for table 1.}
\label{tab:table-1}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Example Column A} & \textbf{Example Column B} \\ 
\hline
Contents A
& Contents B \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\vspace{0.3cm}
\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.5em}
\noindent\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%

\emph{Title for List}: Description of the list. (create/conceptual)
\begin{itemize}[topsep=8pt]
\small
 \item First list item
 \item ...
 \item Last list item
 \end{itemize}
     }
\end{minipage}}

\end{center}
\vspace{0.3cm}

\begin{table}[h]
\vspace{-.1cm}
\small
\caption{Caption for table 2.}
\label{tab:table-2}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Example Column C} & \textbf{Example Column D} \\ 
\hline
Contents C
& Contents D \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How do I suppress the numbering the fbox or parbox or minipage, whichever is triggering the numbering to be included as a table number?

I have tried using the caption package and adding an empty \caption*{}. This did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I tested your code using `\documentclass{article}` and only loading `tabularx` and `enumitem` and I did not get the result you are describing but rather the result you are desiring (namely the correct numbering of both tables). Please post a [minimal (non-)working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/47927) that produces the problem.

Comment: boxes such as fbox and minipage do not increment counters so whatever your problem is, it is not due to the boxes. Please edit the question to have example code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: unrelated but you should not put formatting in a caption like `\caption{\small `  The caption is used in other places (eg list of tables) where the font change is  most likely wrong. You can specify that all captions use a small font globally (using the caption package or other means)

Comment: @JasperHabicht I added a working example with all of the packages I need to include in my document. This code numbers the second table as Table 3.

Comment: My example has been updated to reflect the problem. Maybe the conflict is coming from one of the packages I am including?

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is `ltablex`.

If I comment it from the (reorganized) preamble, the output is

[image]

As soon as I uncomment `\usepackage{ltablex}`, I get

[image]

and you see that also the tables change their shape, besides the numbering being wrong.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{amssymb}% not with acmart
%\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage[font=small,skip=5pt,belowskip=-1pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{ltablex} % <--- this is the problem
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{appendix}

%\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.4cm}
%\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-1pt}
\newcommand*{\affmark}[1][*]{\textsuperscript{#1}}

\fancyhead{}
\makeatletter
\let\@authorsaddresses\@empty
\makeatother

\acmConference[SIGIR '20]{XXX}{XXX}{XXX}
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{} 
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}
\settopmatter{printacmref=false}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}% for centering text horizontally
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}% for vertical centering text in X column

\definecolor{LightGrey}{rgb}{0.93,0.93,0.93}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.8}

\newcommand\boldgray[1]{\cellcolor{lightgray}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand\boldGrey[1]{\cellcolor{LightGrey}{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~~~~\textbullet~~}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\caption{Caption for table 1.}
\label{tab:table-1}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Example Column A} & \textbf{Example Column B} \\ 
\hline
Contents A
& Contents B \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.5em}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \emph{Title for List}: Description of the list. (create/conceptual)
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=8pt]
  \item First list item
  \item ...
  \item Last list item
  \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}% end of \fbox
\end{center}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\caption{Caption for table 2.}
\label{tab:table-2}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Example Column C} & \textbf{Example Column D} \\ 
\hline
Contents C
& Contents D \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Don't load packages multiple times, and separate setup from package loading.

I'm not sure you should load `balance` or `appendix` with `acmart`, nor that you want to change parameters such as `\skip\footins` and `\belowcaptionskip`. Don't load `amssymb`, because the fonts used by the class already support the symbols and you just get an annoying error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to use the interfering `\usepackage{ltablex}`, so I decided to manually number the tables instead.